# Iron-pages with content tag

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

my polymer application has a form wizard which switches though different form sections. 
For this is created a wizard custom dom element. Inside the wizard.html is the iron-pages element.

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="step" selected="{{stepid}}">
  <content/>
</iron-pages>
```

When I now insert the form sections inside my index.html (where I call my wizard) everything works find.

```
<wizard stepId="{{params.stepId}}">
  <section step="1">
    <h2>Step 1</h2>
  </section>
  <section step="2">
    <h2>Step 2</h2>
  </section>
</wizard>
```

But instead I want to add my form steps into another custom element in pass this like:

```
<wizard stepId="{{params.stepId}}">
  <my-form\>
</wizard>
```

Where my-form is an custom element like:

```
<dom-module id="my-form">
<template>
<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
  <section step="1">
    <h2>Step 1</h2>
  </section>
  <section step="2">
    <h2>Step 2</h2>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-form'
</script>
</dom-module>
```

This does not work. Any help how I can manage this?

Comment: that won't work because your `iron-pages` only contains a single child (`<my-form>`). Either you move the `iron-pages`  to your `my-form` element or you need to programtically insert the children (check out the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#effective-children))

Comment: Ok thank you. I moved the iron-pages to my-form. Works